# Curling and PHP to display website page table takes too long to load

Tags: php, html, sql, curl

For my homework, we have 3 websites. Each website has a webpage where we use PHP to dislay a users table from our mysql database. We then must use CURL (required to use CURL) to have a webpage that displays users table from ALL 3 websites.

Below is my code.

For my users list, I simply use PHP to connect to my mysql database and echo out the users table.

For the other 2 websites users list, I use CURL.

However, the professor says that it takes too long to load (takes about 4 seconds I guess)

What should i change in my code or any suggestions as to how to implement this (must use CURL to get other 2 websites users list) and make it faster? Thanks!

```
<?php

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$conn = mysqli_connect("login.ipagemysql.com", "username", "password", "user_website");

if (!$conn) { 
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error($conn)); 
} 


//check comment
$sql = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Address, Home_Phone, Cell 
            FROM Users
           ";





if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th> First_Name </th>";
                echo "<th> Last_Name </th>";
                echo "<th> Email </th>";
                echo "<th> Address </th>";
                echo "<th> Home_Phone </th>";
                echo "<th> Cell_Phone </th>";
             echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Home_Phone'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Cell'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


?>

<br>
<br>
<br>


Website 2 User's List

<?php

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$ch = curl_init("http://website2.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
$match = $match;
}
echo '<table>';

echo  $matches[1] ;
echo '</table>';
curl_close($ch);

?>

<br>
<br>
<br>


Website 3 Users List

<?php

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$ch = curl_init("http://website3.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
$match = $match;
}
echo '<table>';

echo  $match ;
echo '</table>';
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: I don't think that solving your homework problems is the correct use for this site.  That said, you should try to isolate the part of your code that is causing the performance issue.  I would do that by commenting out small portions of the code until it works better.  If you could reduce the problem code down to a few lines, it would be easier to help find a solution for you.

Comment: I mean, when asking a question, stackoverflow asks you to choose a type and one of the choices is: "I need help with a homework problem"......Perhaps if it bothers you, you can just ignore these homework type problems.